# ValidateCredentials requires run as administrator on some machines

Tags: c#, active-directory, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a WPF .NET Core 3.1 app that queries AD via ValidateCredentials and on some machines, it throws an exception unless it is run as admin.  Here is the code;

```
var context = PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
context = context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
```

As I said it works on some machines and not others.  What would cause some machines to require run as admin?

edit:

Sorry forgot to post the exception:

> ActiveDirectoryValidation.AuthUserAD Error validating user
> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException: The
> server cannot handle directory requests.    at
> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ErrorChecking.CheckAndSetLdapError(Int32
> error)    at
> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapSessionOptions.FastConcurrentBind()
> at
> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.BindLdap(NetworkCredential
> creds, ContextOptions contextOptions)    at
> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.Validate(String
> userName, String password)    at
> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(String
> userName, String password)

Comment: `throws an exception` and those exception details? On another note, you should be constructing a new instance of `PrincipalContext` and use `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity` to ensure the user actually exist first before going any further with validating credentials.

Comment: @zaggler just added the error message.  Good idea about checking first

Comment: Can you try adding `ContextOptions.Negotiate` to the `ValidateCredentials` call? For example: `context.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);` [Here's more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.validatecredentials?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_PrincipalContext_ValidateCredentials_System_String_System_String_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_ContextOptions_) on that overload.

Comment: @zaggler I was really trying not to do a code change.  Code is in production and turnaround will be slow.  I did see that information before.